# How to add table that has foreign key value referring to another table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

**Model 1:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class productDescription extends Model
{
    protected $table="ProductDescription";
    protected $connection="mysql";

    public function productPricing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(priceInfo::class);
    }
    public function salesPackage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(packageModel::class);
    }
}
```

**Model2:**

```
class packageModel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table="subSalesPackage";
    protected $connection="mysql";

    public function product_description(){
        return $this->belongsTo(productDescription::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function addProductDetails(Request $formdescription,$dataId)
{
    $description=new productDescription;
    $description->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
    $description->productdescriptionid=$this->getproductDescriptionId();
    $description->modelName=$formdescription->input('mname');

    $description->batteryType=$formdescription->input('batteryType');
    //$description->salesPackage =$formdescription->input('package');
    $description->skillSet =$formdescription->input('skillSet');
    $description->Colour=$formdescription->input('colour');
    $description->Material =$formdescription->input('material');
    $description->maxAge=$formdescription->input('maxage');
    $description->minAge =$formdescription->input('minage');

    //$product->productPricing()-save($priceInfo); 
    //$product->productDetails()->save($description);
    $description->save();

    $salesPackage=new packageModel;
    $salesPackage->salesPackage=$formdescription->input('package');
    **$salesPackage->product_description()->associate($description);**
    $salesPackage->save();
    //echo("success");

    return response()->json([
        'modelName'    => $formdescription->mname,
        'colour' => $formdescription->colour,
        'rechargable' => $formdescription->rechargable,
        'batteryType' => $formdescription->batteryType
    ]);

    //$description->product()->associate($priceInfo);
}
```

**Migration->productdescription:**

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('ProductDescription', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine='InnoDB';
        $table->string('productdescriptionid')->primary();
        $table->string('product_id');

          $table->string('salesPackage');
        $table->timestamps();  
        $table->index(['productDescriptionId']);  

    });
}
```

This is my migration for 1st table(model).It has the primary key as'productdescriptionid'.

**Migration->subSalespackage**

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('subSalesPackage', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('product_description_id');
        $table->string('salesPackage');
        $table->foreign('product_description_id')-
     >references('productdescriptionid')->on('ProductDescription');
        $table->timestamps();  
        $table->index(['id']);  
    });
}
```

Here I have referred the productdescriptionid as foreign key.And when I add this salespackage table,the values should get added with the value of `productdescriptionid(productDescription)`.

But the error i'm getting is can't able to add or update a child row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
return response()->json([
  'SKUID' => $priceInfo->SKUID,
  'listingStatus' => $priceInfo->listingStatus,
  'MRP' => $priceInfo->MRP,
  'sellingPrice' => $priceInfo->sellingPrice,
  'id' =>$this->getproductId()
]);
```